# Excel VBA RC Notation with Variable and Array

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a formula that is being pasted from row 2 to the last row of multiple columns that is driven by an array.

I have nearly all of the code working, except for the variable that I have within the formula is changing row count in each row, which I do not want.

I created a variable 'VARIA' that increases 1 with each iteration of the array, so that is working properly. My issue is that for each cell, let's say C2-C100, VARIA is pulling increased row count, so the formula in Cell A2 will have location C2 from the FinderHeaders tab, and cell C3 will have location C3 from the FindersHeaders tab.

What I am trying to do is have all cells (C2-C100) for the array iteration be A1, next array iteration (F2-F100) be A2, next array iteration (I2-I100) be A3.

I have absolutely no idea why the VARIA variable is not working properly as it is staying the same variable for the entire array iteration.

```
  wsMain.Cells(rng.Row + 1, LastColumn).Resize(LR - 1).Formula = "=IF(ISBLANK(R[0]C1),VLOOKUP(R[0]C4,'CRR-R Data'!C1:C27,MATCH(FinderHeaders!R[" & VARIA & "]C1,'CCW-R Data'!R2C3:R2C27,0)+1,0),VLOOKUP(R[0]C4,'CRR-R Data'!C2:C27,MATCH(FinderHeaders!R[" & VARIA & "]C1,'CCW-R Data'!R1C3:R1C27,0)+1,0))"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well.... I just had to remove the []s apparently and it worked.